# How to vertically position/align yaxis title at bottom in plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to create a plotly express line chart with a yaxis title that is positioned at the bottom of the axis instead of the center.  This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly import express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(0,10)})
fig = px.line(df).update_layout(yaxis_anchor='free', yaxis_position=0)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this location of the axes titles can't be changed. The argument `yaxis_position=0` won't work because that changes the x coordinate of the yaxis in the plotting space.

However one possible workaround would be to set the yaxis title to an empty string, then place the text down as an [annotation](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#text-annotations) at the correct location and angle.

For example:

```
fig = px.line(df).update_yaxes(title='')
fig.add_annotation(x=-0.05, y=0, xref="paper", yref="y", showarrow=False, text="value", font=dict(size=14), textangle=-90)
```

[image]